# How to apply a default filter on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have an entity data model (User, SecurityProfile and OrganizationalUnit as entities). There is 1:1 connection between User and OrganizationalUnit, n:n connection between SecurityProfile and OrganizationalUnit and 1:0 connection between User and SecurityProfile.

Basically we have users, few users have administrative privileges (SecurityProfiles). One administrator can administer one or more organizational units and all of the users under this.

Is there any way that when I access entity.OrganizationalUnits than the returning set would be automatically filtered by a security logic? It is a MVC2 project, so I can always retrieve the current identity and the roles and also the logic is available that would make the filtering I just don't know how and where to insert to automatically apply it. Is it techically possible at all?

thanks in advance

Comment: What you have described is business logic. EF will not perform your business logic automatically. You have to create queries which will use your logic. You can wrap data access to classes which will ensure that proper security restriction are used.

Comment: i was afraid of that :-/

Comment: You could create a view in SQL Server that shows only those user entries you want - and then model that view in EF

Comment: but in sql server i don't know who is the logged in user. The returned list should be different for each logged in administrator.